# Sitecore 9 forms giving error when click form launchpad icon

Tags: sitecore-forms

When we click on Forms icon from Launchpad in Sitecore 9, we are getting the error below:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary
requires a model item of type 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Structures.Substructures.GlobalHeaders.GlobalHeaderRenderingModel'.
```

[image]

Comment: Is that an upgraded solution or fresh install?

Comment: Do you see any information in the log file?

Comment: This sounds like an upgraded solution.  I ran into the same issue.  I had missed one of the steps in the upgrade documentation.  You may to go through the upgrade documentation for WFFM and ensure that all steps were followed.