# Exception when opening the Sitecore 9 Forms application

Tags: upgrade, sitecore-forms

I get a yellow-screen-of-death after clicking the `Forms` application icon from the launchpad:

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Structures.Substructures.GlobalHeaders.GlobalHeaderRenderingModel'.`

[image: Screenshot of error]

I found this other [question that appears similar](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18384/sitecore-9-forms-giving-error-when-click-form-launchpad-icon). A comment there suggests that this error could be caused by missing a step from the upgrade procedure. We did recently run through an upgrade to 9.0.1 from 8.1.0.

Any ideas where I might start looking to figure out this issue?

I am also a little confused as to where the file in question is. The path that the error message displays (`/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Substructures/GlobalHeader.cshtml`) for the Razor view does not even exist in my filesystem. I double-checked this against the provided [Sitecore 9.0.1 files](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/3093D892E19B4ACFB2DC68622C18E409.ashx) from the [upgrade documentation](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/90/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_90_Update1.aspx), and sure enough, the file doesn't exist there either. There does not seem to be a `Structures` folder in the `/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings` directory.

Comment: Compare your files with those from a clean Sitecore install...  that is normally the way to fix issues with these errors after upgrading

Comment: @Gatogordo Oof, that was tedious! I went through the entire application file structure and looked for file differences. Nothing in particular jumped out that looked related to this issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you check `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Substructures/GlobalHeader` in the core database? The model should match `Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Structures.Substructures.GlobalHeaders.GlobalHeaderRenderingModel,Sitecore.Speak.Components`

Comment: That's getting closer; the model field was blank! I do believe this solved this particular error. I am getting further errors that look simliar to this `The model item passed in...`, but this seems to have solved this particular error. Thank you! If you create an answer, I'll be happy to mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify the items `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Substructures/GlobalHeader` (and related) in the core database. They have a model and it seems that those are not correct. The model for the GlobalHeader should match `Sitecore.Speak.Components.Models.Structures.Substructures.GlobalHeaders.GlobalHeaderRenderingModel,Sitecore.Speak.Components`.

If you keep getting these errors, try installing a blank Sitecore 9.0.1 and compare the core databases.

Comment: Thanks! I did end up grabbing a Core database from a working site and using that in my site. I am now able to see the forms application.